# Alphabet navigation for magento categories

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to implement an easier form of navigation for my list of categories, I was wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction of how I would go about setting up an alphabetic navigation system above my list of categories. The user must be able to press on either "A" or "B" and it will only display the categories which name begins with that letter.

I am populating my list of categories as follows:

```
<?php $children = explode( ",", $this->getCurrentCategory()->getChildren() ); ?>
<div class="category-products">
    <ul class="products-list">
        <?php foreach( $children as $child ): ?>
            <?php $_child = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/category' )->load( $child ); ?>
                <li class="item">
                    <img class="product-image" src="<?php echo $_child->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
                    <h3> <?php echo $_child->getName() ?> </h3>
                    <div class="cat-desc">
                        <?php echo $_child->getDescription(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cat-list-nav">
                        <a href="<?php echo $_child->getUrl(); ?>">
                            <input type="button" onClick="window.location.href='<?php echo $_child->getUrl(); ?>'" value="Browse Shop"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: You could print all categories and simple use javascript to setup the alphabet filtering (hide/show) categories that start with that letter. Another way would be to create a controller, register a variable (register('category-letter', 'A')) and read that letter in the phtml

Comment: Thanks, the javascript filtering seems simple enough. I will try and see what I can do. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Think you are looking for the functionality like this :
[image: Alpabatical Navigation Jquery]
For This Use Following Code :

jquery code :

```
<script>
$x = jQuery.noConflict();
$x(function() {
    var _alphabets = $x('.alphabet > a');
    var _contentRows = $x('#countries-table tbody tr');

    _alphabets.click(function() {
        var _letter = $x(this), _text = $x(this).text(), _count = 0;

        _alphabets.removeClass("active");
        _letter.addClass("active");

        _contentRows.hide();
        _contentRows.each(function(i) {
            var _cellText = $x(this).children('td').eq(0).text();
            if (RegExp('^' + _text).test(_cellText)) {
                _count += 1;
                $x(this).fadeIn(400);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

phtml Code :

```
<?php $innerhtml = "";
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
<?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): 
$innerhtml.="<tr><td><a href=".$_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category).">".$_category->getName()."</a></td></tr>"; ?>
    <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
    <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
    <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
        <?php foreach ($_subcategories as $_subcategory): 
            $innerhtml.="<tr><td><a href=".$_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory).">".$_subcategory->getName()."</a></td></tr>"; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>   
<?php endif; ?> 
<h1>Product Categories</h1>
<div class="alphabet" style="">
<a class="first" href="#">A</a>
<a href="#">B</a>
<a href="#">C</a>
<a href="#">D</a>
<a href="#">E</a>
<a href="#">F</a>
<a href="#">G</a>
<a href="#">H</a>
<a href="#">I</a>
<a href="#">J</a>
<a href="#">K</a>
<a href="#">L</a>
<a href="#">M</a>
<a href="#">N</a>
<a href="#">O</a>
<a href="#">P</a>
<a href="#">Q</a>
<a href="#">R</a>
<a href="#">S</a>
<a href="#">T</a>
<a href="#">U</a>
<a href="#">V</a>
<a href="#">W</a>
<a href="#">X</a>
<a href="#">Y</a>
<a class="last" href="#">Z</a>
</div>
<div id="conutries">
<table id="countries-table">
<thead><tr><th>Category Name</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
    <?php echo $innerhtml; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Stylesheet is :

```
#conutries
{
    width: 650px;
    background: white;
}
#countries-table
{
    border-spacing: 2px;
}
.alphabet
{
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.alphabet a, #countries-table tr
{
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.alphabet a
{
    width: 20px;
    float: left;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 2px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    border-right: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
}
.alphabet a.first
{
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
.alphabet a.last
{
    border-right: 1px solid silver;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
.alphabet a:hover,
.alphabet a.active
{
    background: #FBF8E9;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for this amazing response! I am unable to try it all out now, I will let you know by tomorrow if it works and tag your answer as the best. Thank you so much again!